# Duas threads executando uma mesma função

Tags: delphi, thread

Eu tenho uma situação onde em Delphi possuo duas threads que executam uma função que faz um ping em um banco de dados Firebird.

Utilizo isso para sincronizar dados do meu PDV (enviando e recebendo).

Mas como eles executam ao mesmo tempo as vezes ocorre um dead lock no BD.

--

Minha função:

```
function TTPingRede(const IP: AnsiString; TimeOut: Integer = 250) : Boolean;
var
       DW: DWORD;
   Handle: THandle;
   InAddr: IPAddr;
      Arq: TextFile;
      Rep: array[1..128] of byte;`
begin
    try
       DW     := 99;
       Result := False;
       Handle := IcmpCreateFile;
if (Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
       begin
try
              TranslateStringToTInAddr(PansiChar(IP), InAddr);
              DW := IcmpSendEcho(Handle, InAddr, nil, 0, nil, @rep, 128, TimeOut);
              Result := (DW <> 0);
              vStatusREDE_ATIVA := Result;
           except
               DW     := 0;
               Result := False;
           end;
try
              Dm.qStatusRede.Close;
              Dm.qStatusRede.SQL.Clear;
              Dm.qStatusRede.SQL.Add('UPDATE TBSINCRO001');
              Dm.qStatusRede.SQL.Add('SET');
              Dm.qStatusRede.SQL.Add('   STATUS_REDE_SERVIDOR = :P0');
              Dm.qStatusRede.Params[0].AsInteger := DW;
              Dm.qStatusRede.Prepare;
              Dm.qStatusRede.ExecSQL;
if Dm.Tr_StatusRede.InTransaction then Dm.Tr_StatusRede.Commit;
           except
               on E: Exception do
               begin
                   Dm.Tr_StatusRede.Rollback;
                   GerarLogErroSincronizar('1:FUNC ENV|'+E.Message);
               end;
           end;
       end;
    finally
IcmpCloseHandle(Handle);
    end;
end;
```

Eu gostaria de saber uma implementação que eu consiga pingar no banco sem ocorrer o dead lock.

Comment: Aqui é a versão em português, precisa traduzir a pergunta.

Comment: Não sei o motivo de estar usando duas threads para o mesmo objetivo, mas a forma mais simples (e obvia) de resolver seria deixando apenas uma thread... Outra forma seria usando "critical sections"... Pesquise no Google sobre isso e veja também este vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiX5ra36Las

Answer (score 1):

Problemas com concorrência geralmente tem uma causa em comum: objetos compartilhados

Neste caso, parece que o objeto compartilhado `Dm` é usado pelas duas *threads*. Isso significa que as duas *threads* estão enviando e recebendo dados na mesma conexão. Pense nisso como dois usuários digitando comandos SQL num mesmo teclado, um interfere no outro mesmo sem commit.

De alguma forma, você precisa garantir que cada *thread* execute numa conexão independente. A forma mais simples de fazer isso é criar `Dm1` e `Dm2` e atribuir cada um para uma *thread*. Uma forma mais elaborada seria criar uma conexão dentro do escopo da *thread*. Pense nisso como dois usuários acessando o mesmo banco de dados de terminais diferentes, portanto com sessões distintas e um não interfere no outro até efetuar o commit da transação.

Comment: Aqui eu uso firebirb, da forma que você falou funciona perfeitamente! Acho que no caso dele será a mesma coisa!

Answer (score 0):

A pilha TCP/IP organiza sessões entre servidores e clientes por meio do PID do processo em cada extremo da conexão.
Como duas threads fazem parte de um mesmo processo, acredito que estão compartilhando uma sessão com o servidor de SGBD, o que lhe causa DeadLock. Experimente criar dois processos distintos, um para cada requisição ao servidor.